# Rename a server without logging in?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there anyway to rename a server without be able to log into it? We have a file server that keeps rebooting, so we built another and transferred all the data. Only issue is renaming the old one while not being able to log on to it.

Comment: If it keeps rebooting and you replaced it why do you need to rename it?

Answer (score 1):

If the server is in AD, you could use `netdom` command:

```
netdom renamecomputer [old_name] /newName:[new_name] /userd:[administrative_username] /passwordd:*
```

`passwordd:*` will promt you for the password of the user.

If you can't access the server at all (e.g. all user accounts lost/disabled, no access possible due to permanent rebooting) i think this will not work - you need some kind of privileged access to the machine - netdom command still needs to 'log in'.

Without any kind of access, i don't see a way to change the name of the machine itself - if it is replaced, i would just disable it (if it is a domain member) and/or shut it down.